# minikube start failed with ssh error

Tags: minikube

I got this error when start minikube. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

I1105 12:57:36.987582   15567 cluster.go:77] Machine state:  Running
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Getting to WaitForSSH function...
Using SSH client type: native
&{{{ 0 [] [] []} docker [0x83b300] 0x83b2b0  [] 0s} 127.0.0.1 22  }
About to run SSH command:
exit 0
Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

Answer (score 2):

In order to have local instance of cluster-like Kubernetes installation there is [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/) utility.

This tool can do all the magic of the installation process automatically.

In the short - the process of deploying consist of downloading runtime images, spinning up containers and configuring necessary elements of Kubernetes without any user interaction required. It works like a charm.

You may consider to just drop current installation and start it over?

Looks like

> minikube delete && minikube start

may help.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the .minikube file and starting minikube helps.

```
rm -rf ~/.minikube & minikube start
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are running as an administrator.
- Performing this would be enough
  `minikube delete && minikube start`